# Python input, ifstatement, return

Tags: if-statement, python-3.x, return-value

I have to create a function that takes an input, and returns a corresponding Grade.

So for example if the user inputs A+ output is 90%
or 
if the input is A output is 80%
or 
if the input is B output is 70%

I have some sort of Idea on how to do this... but I am having trouble on wrapping my head around on how I can return the statement??

def percent (percentage):

```
if ( percentage )== A+
return ("90%")
elif (percentage)== A
return ("80%")
```

Is this the correct way of going about it?

Comment: Hello one more question ! What if someone enters the value 91 or 89 ... I would like the program to give A+ for all values above 90 ... so will this code word for such a function as well?

Answer (score 0):

OK, so first, welcome to Python. Second, this is Pythonic way of doing this - define a dict:

```
grades = {'A+': "90%", 'A': "80%", ...}
```

then

```
return grades[precentage]
```

will do the job.

You need to protect against the case where the grade is not in the dict, for example, if the user entered some mistake, like G. There are a few ways to go about that:

A simple if:

```
if precentage in grades:
    return grades[precentage]
else:
    return "bad precentage"
```

After you get used to Python you will be more aesthetic about your code and will want to do better than state twice bote grades and precentage, so you can do simply:

```
return grades.get(precentage, "bad precentage")
```

Or using a special dict with default values:

```
import collections
grades = collections.defaultdict(lambda: "bad precentage", [("A+", "90%"), ("A", "80%")])
```

then

```
grades[precentage]
```

will automatically return "bad precentage" upon bad input.

Comment: Hello one more question !
What if someone enters the value 91 or 89 ... I would like the program to give A+ for all values above 90 ... so will this code word for such a function as well?

Answer (score 0):

@user2829744  You don't want to have to repeatedly call if statements based on what the percentage is, that would make the code unnecessarily long.

Instead, you want to have a list or tuple (a variable which stores multiple elements) that the program can compare the user's inputted value to, and then calculate the percentage mark.

Take this for example:

```
def percentage(per):

 grades=["A+","A","B","C","D","E","F"]
 percentage=("90%","80%","70%","60%","50%","40%","30%")
 for i in range(7):
  if per.upper()==grades[i]:
   return percentage[i]

d="a"
print(percentage(d))
```

What happens is that `i` counts up to the number seven, and if the value of `i` in grades (let's say `i` is 5, then that would be grades[5] which would be an "E") then the function returns the value of `i` in the percentage tuple.  In my case, the interpreter outputs 80%

Logically, your way of going about it (by actually dealing with every grade possible in separate if statements) would work too, however like I said your code would be longer and chances are you'd make a few typos along the way that you'd have to edit. Of course, my code has a few problems too, like what if the user enters a grade which I don't have in the tuple.  This is easily fixable though as you would just need to tell the interpreter what to do if that happens.

A bit brief I know, but I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this

```
    user_input = int(input("percentage:  ")
    if user_input < 0 and user_input > 10:
         print('F")
```

And then you can just duplicate the code and change the numbers and the return grade
Hope it helps :)